# Mongoose's Model.findByIdAndDelete() successfully deletes document but hangs afterwards

Tags: mongoose, postman, router, express-router, mongoose-deleteone

I am using express with mongoose and MongoDB. After creating a simple deletion route for my "Quiz" model, it deletes the document, however it never actually receives a response. I have tested with Postman and Insomnia.

Here is my controller:

```
const removeQuizById = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    quiz = await Quizz.findById(id);
    if (quiz) {
      await Quizz.findByIdAndDelete(id);
      res.status(200);
    } else {
      res.status(404);
      throw new Error("quiz does not exist");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
};

module.exports = { getQuizById, removeQuizById };
```

This is the route:
`router.route("/quiz/:id").get(getQuizById).delete(removeQuizById);`

Here is a response of a GET, so you can see the quiz does exist:
[return of Get in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mutFP.png)

Here is what happens when using the delete route: [Delete in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeOsV.png)

And here is after canceling and sending one more time, to confirm the document was indeed deleted:[Response after sending one more time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl7be.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.status(200)` does not end the response.

try `res.sendStatus(200)`